# Pushing rdoc documentation to rubygems.org

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc

So I wrote a small ruby gem and documented it with rdoc. But I don't know how to get my documentation onto rubygems. Anyone know?

Comment: Are you just asking how to push your gem? Otherwise rubydoc.info will automatically handle this for you it just might take a little while (maybe a day or so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload your gem into rubygems.org, it automatically uploads the documentation in rubydoc.info

The guide to upload the gem: http://guides.rubygems.org/publishing/

hope it helps